# Issue when uploading a file to a bucket on Google cloud platfrom using python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, bucket

When I upload a text file to a bucket in GCP (using python) the file is 0KB and the file does not contain any content.

The Code:

```
from google.cloud import storage

f = open("myText.txt", "w")
f.write("Yo\n")
f.write("awe")

def upload_blob(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name):
  """Uploads a file to the bucket."""


  storage_client = storage.Client()

  bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
  blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)

  blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)


  print('File {} uploaded to {}.'.format(
      source_file_name,
      destination_blob_name))


upload_blob('dev_kfp', 'myText.txt', "myTextOnline.txt")
```

The file gets uploaded with 0 errors, but the file size is 0Kb and the file does not contain anything. Please asisst. When I opne the file on File explorer it does contain the content. The type of the file is text/plain on GCP bucket.

Thank you!

Comment: Not sure if you have tried. Why not close the file before trying to upload. f.close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm able reproduce your issue and as per @mjkool after closing the file on the script the uploaded file has the size on the bucket. Here is the updated script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from google.cloud import storage

f = open("myText.txt", "w")
f.write("Yo\n")
f.write("awe")
f.close()

def upload_blob(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name):
  """Uploads a file to the bucket."""


  storage_client = storage.Client()

  bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
  blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)

  blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)


  print('File {} uploaded to {}.'.format(
      source_file_name,
      destination_blob_name))


upload_blob('my_bucket', 'myText.txt', "myTextOnline.txt")
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! Can't believe it was something so simple.